# What Html markup for a focusable TD?

Tags: html, focus, markup

I want to practive, and even best-practice, with Html+JS+CSS.
I use a one page client-only Sudoku page.
My Sudoku markup is basically a `<table>`, with `<td>`.
(I'm open to suggestions to improve this).

My requirements :

1. Have a **cell under focus** (the keyboard notion of focus) (highlighed with css to a yellow background)
2. Navigate through cells with arrow keys (plus Home etc).
3. type-in an integer value sets that value to the currently focused cell

I use an input button inside each cell.
The Javascript works fine.

My only problem is with the display.
**When a cell has the focus, it's highlighted display doesn't cover the whole TD**, rather only the visual space included in the input button. I have some space around the button that isn't 'yellow'.

I don't think I could go up in the CSS selection, to select the parent of the input, could I ? Such as :

```
input:focus '?? how to go up ??' td { background-color:yellow;
```

I tried a few tricks, like having always 5 characters in each button display (5 spaces when empty, changing the middle character when set), but nothing is visually satisfying.
Even worse, it is clearly against best-practices to alter the content for the sake of visualizing. That's what the MVC distinction between Html/Css/Js is for !

I already searched this site for answer, I found close but distinct questions and answer.

I'm hoping someone could help improve my page ... and my markup skill :-)

Comment: Could you supply a bit of HTML that your using for the sudoku table?

Comment: Something like "<table><tr><td><input type="button" value=""/> ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to construct a css selector which matches a parent node dependent on a (pseudo-)class of child node.

Basically you have two options to choose from:

- Try to fill the `td` with the `input` completely using `height` and `width` rules in your css.
- Set 'focused' and 'unfocused' class on your tds with javascript using the `onfocus` and `onblur` events of the inputs.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation for the CSS selector.

I will try your javascript proposal.

I also wish to try to height and width rules, but I had problem making them work reliably (for changing content) before...

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use a dash of jQuery to set a .focused class and then apply some style to it?